# sublime text 3 windows portable version upgrade

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using a windows portable version of sublime text 3. I already have some custom settings and packages installed in my current version say Build 3065.

How can I upgrade the build version to the newest one and also keep my settings and packages?
Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the Windows portable install `.zip` file for the latest build (currently 3083 for the [public beta](http://sublimetext.com/3), 3084 if you run the [dev builds](http://sublimetext.com/3dev)). Go to the directory where you installed Sublime, make sure that the program is completely closed, then delete everything in that directory ***except*** the `Data` folder, which is where all your personalized settings and stuff are kept. Then, open the `.zip` file in another Windows Explorer window, select everything in the file except `Data`, and copy it all back to your original install directory. Fire up Sublime again, and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Just let sublime text update itself, and it will keep everything you installed.

Comment: How? This answer isn't helpful if you don't provide the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Sublime Text is not running.
The Data folder in your current installation is the key folder. So make sure you don't touch it until your new installation is in place. Better to keep a backup of it with a date tag.

So extract the latest zip file you have downloaded for Sublime Text and delete the "Data" folder in the new extraction(installation). I prefer this approach to use the new unzip folder since it'll carry the version number in its folder name. 
But if you are using a generic folder name for Sublime Text and it's mapped to some other dependency, then rename the old installation's main folder name with an "_old" and rename the new installation's main folder name with the generic name.

After that just copy the "Data" folder from the current installation to the new installation folder and then start Sublime Text and you are done.